# using data range in python incorrect syntax error

Tags: python

I have been working on this script I need to know  how to use date range like  if want to look at the data from last week can i use `dl_date =   datetime.date.today() - 5days`. It gives me incorrect syntax error.

```
    try:
    site_id = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        dl_date = sys.argv[2]
    except:
        oneday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        dl_date = datetime.date.today() - oneday
except:
    print "Usage: %s site_id [date]"
    sys.exit(1)

# Process the cameras for that site
for cam_id in cam_id_list:
    cam_name = db_obj.cam_name_by_id(cam_id)
    print "Downloading %s for %s" % (cam_name, dl_date)
    try:
        #myftp = anprint.ftpClient(cam_name)
    rsync = anprint.ftpClient(cam_name)
        #dl_count = myftp.downloaddir(dl_date)
        dl_count = rsync.downloaddir(dl_date)
    db_obj.log_stats(cam_id, dl_count, dl_date)

        fp = open(stats_filename, "a")
        stats_string = "Downloaded %d entries from %s\n" % (dl_count, cam_name)
        fp.write(stats_string)
        fp.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: That's not valid Python. Please indent your code.

Comment: You get a `SyntaxError` (please **provide the full traceback**, by the way) because your syntax is wrong. The indentation is incorrect, and names can't start with numbers (`2day`). Also, you [shouldn't use bare `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/) (and if you do, why would you expect there to be anything left for the second one to catch?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [timedelata](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#timedelta-objects)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
dl_date  = date.today() - timedelta(days=5)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sk11 thats it.. Sk11 is it possible to rsync wihtout using date on my script..

Answer (score 0):

dateutil package will be very helpful

```
import dateutil.relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print now + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(weeks=-1)
```